# Questions regarding internal and interior points for a convex subset of a topological vector space

Tags: convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a topological vector space, with a convex subset $A$. How do we show that if the vector $u$ is in the interior of $A$, then $u$ is an internal point of $A$ and if the interior of $A$ is nonempty with $u$ an internal point of $A$, then $u$ is in the interior of $A$? Finally, is there some good example of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an internal point which is not an interior point?

So far, I have read that $x_0$ is an internal point of a subset $Y$ of $X$, provided that for any $y \in X$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x_0 + ty \in Y$ for $|t| < \delta$, but other than that, I'm not really sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 3):

In a finite-dimensional topological vector space, interior points and internal points coincide for convex sets.
This is no longer true in infinite dimension.
Here is [a reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA200) for these two facts.

Now let us find a counter-example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ when $A$ is not convex.
Consider the set $A$ consisting of the union of:

- the region delimited by the graphs of $\sqrt{x}$ and $-\sqrt{x}$ over $[0,+\infty)$
- the region delimited by the graphs of $\sqrt{-x}$ and $-\sqrt{-x}$ over $(-\infty,0]$
- the line $y$-axis $\{x=0\}$

Then convince yourself that $(0,0)$ is internal, but not in the interior of $A$.

Comment: @Libertron Did this help?